# Problem with arbitrary values on Tailwind with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a react component that changes the width from a parameter but it's doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
function Bar() {
    
    const p =80

    const style = `bg-slate-500 h-8 w-[${p.toFixed(1)}%]`

    console.log(style)

    return (
        <div className=' h-8 w-full'>
            <div className={`bg-slate-500 h-8 w-[${p}%]`}>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Bar
```

With this code I get a full-size bar, but if I use a strict String with 80.0 it works fine

Comment: You're using arbitrary values incorrectly. Have a look at the first paragraph under `Dynamic values` https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support `your classes need to exist as complete strings for Tailwind to detect them correctly`.

Comment: You can use css variables in some caese `text-[color:var(--your-val)]` and that pass it through `style={ { '--your-var': '#fff' }}`

Comment: What is your filename? Including extension

Comment: Newer docs for V3+: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The other answers are wrong. In Tailwind V3 JIT is included and you won't need to set mode to jit anymore. And even in Tailwind V2 the posted code wouldn't work.

Following the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#classes-aren-t-generated), you must avoid string interpolation and use complete class names.

This is **wrong**:

```js
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
```

Instead use **Complete class names**:

```js
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
```

**What about using inline styles?**

You may be tempted to use inline styles, but remember Content Security Policies are increasingly under scrutiny to disallow *unsafe inlines*. Any inline `style` or `script` could in theory be injected with unintended content. Furthermore, the whole point to Tailwind is to generate CSS at build time, so you'd be working around it and might as well not even be using it in this case.

Comment: Why is the first approach wrong?

Comment: @sir https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support , also applies to V3 unless they changed it recently

Comment: You still need to manually enable `jit` in tailwind.config as of today. The thing OP did wrong was use string concatenation to build the class, as described in the docs under "Dynamic Values" here. https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#overview

Comment: @sir because Tailwind is generating classes at build time and won't be aware of the value of `padding`, so the class `p-[80%]` won't be exported. Nevertheless, if you add `p-[80%]` in the safelist array, Tailwind will then add this class at build time. But there is no point on doing this because it would only work for `padding = 80;`

Comment: @MaximeLechevallier but inline styles are insecure aren't they? For instance, CORS policy can only permit them with unsafe inline, which is really not always an option... Also, this completely defeats the purpose of tailwind by working around its API doesn't it?

Comment: @ecoe I agree with you, my last sentence meant that there is no point on writing the code this way, just go for `<div className="p-[80%]">`. (btw not sure it's the best way to write it, `p-4/5` looks nicer). Anyway my bad, I haven't fully read the code of the question.

Comment: @MaximeLechevallier I'm still not sure if I follow what you meant. Ever since V2 tailwind has supported "JIT", which means you can write dynamic class names like `<div className={ size === 'lg' ? 'mt-[22px]' : 'mt-[17px]' }></div>` as stated in [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#classes-aren-t-generated). So, as long as there is a predefined (at build-time) super set of options, you can _dynamically_ generate classes still.

Comment: @ecoe Hmm right, haven't seen he was using "JIT" (brackets signature), then my answer is pointless, no need of the safelist.

Comment: I encountered this issue when I applying min height to a div, but I came across a weird behaviour. While according to the docs as @wizard003 mentioned, I should not be using string interpolated class names, I manage to get tailwind to pick up on specific numbers such as 800 but not the others. Using the solution above didn't make a difference. I did notice, however, by including a static class name (ie: `min-h-[1000px]`) tailwind was able to generate the appropriate class name. Any ideas on alternatives to this solution? I'm trying to create templated pages with react and I'm getting stumped.

Answer (score 18):

I had exactly the same problem as you.

```
const p =80
<div className={`bg-slate-500 h-8 w-[${p}%]`}>
```

The above code set "w-[${p}%]" as "w-80%" *dynamically* on the server side. However Tailwind has no ability to deal with the arbitrary values computed dynamically.

The official [Tailwind docs](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support) say;

[image: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support]

To work around this problem, we need to use `style` attribute like following in which we are not able to use TailwindCSS anymore;

```
<div
  style={{width: `${p}%`}} 
  className={`bg-slate-500 h-8`}>
```

[See the discussions on GitHub](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/10132)

I hope it helps you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

in `tailwind.config.js` add `mode: 'jit'`.

I would suggest https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode to learn more.

e.g:

```
module.exports = {
   //other options
   mode: 'jit',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your p's value is a constant that will be used across the app, you can instead define it in your `tailwind.config.js` file like this.

```
theme: {
 extend: {
  spacing: {
    "p-value": "80%",
  },
 }, 
}
```

Then you can modify your code to this.

```
<div className="bg-slate-500 h-8 w-p-value">
```

Answer (score 1):

in React with tailwind Styles follow this pattern:

```
<div className={`bg-red-500 flex w-[70%] h-[70%]`} style={{boxShadow: `${horizantal}px ${vertical}px ${blur}px ${spraied}px ${color}`}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue building a site with Astro & Tailwind.

The solution I discovered was to use the 'safelist' feature that allows you to define certain classes that will be force-compiled, regardless of whether or not they are found when scanning the specified content locations in the tailwind.config.cjs file.

An example of the code I used to fix my situation:

```
module.exports = {
content: ["./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}"],
Adding a safelist and classes to it:
safelist: ["lg:grid-cols-[1fr_4fr]", "lg:grid-cols-[1fr_3fr_1fr]"],
...
```

[Here's a link to the relevant area in the Tailwind documentation.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)

Answer (score -1):

Include mode: 'jit' in tailwind config file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).